# How I can browse this result returned by an AJAX request with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How I can browse this result returned by an AJAX request with jQuery?

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyFunction(comp_id) {
    var user_id = document.getElementById("user").value;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "chart.php?q="+comp_id+"&u="+user_id ,
    data: "call=test",
    success: function(Array){

        alert(Array);


    }
});
}
</script>
```

my result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valeur] => 70
            [date] => 2016-02-19 11:46:37
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [valeur] => 40
            [date] => 2016-02-19 11:50:38
        )
)
```

How I can browse this result.

thank you in advance

Comment: Browse how? If you do `console.log(Array)` and open the browser console, you can "browse" it ?

Comment: I need to display ( value date) (70,2016-02-19 11:46:37) & (40,2016-02-19 11:50:38)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Note: Array must be json encoded

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyFunction(comp_id) {
    var user_id = document.getElementById("user").value;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "chart.php?q="+comp_id+"&u="+user_id ,
    data: "call=test",
    success: function(Array){

        $.each( Array, function( key, value ) {
            alert( value.valeur + ", " + value.date );
        });
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Your php response must be

```
json_encode(Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valeur] => 70
            [date] => 2016-02-19 11:46:37
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [valeur] => 40
            [date] => 2016-02-19 11:50:38
        )
));
```

You can see it in you browser's console panel. (F12 key to open console panel in most browser)

Comment: I need to display ( value date) (70,2016-02-19 11:46:37) & (40,2016-02-19 11:50:38)

Answer (score 0):

You can read each individual result of your multidimensional array like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "chart.php?q="+comp_id+"&u="+user_id ,
    data: {call: "test"},
    success: function(Array){

        for(var i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
            var result = Array[i];
            var valeur = result['valeur'];
            var date = result['date'];

            // You can use these variables now :). For example:
            alert("Entry " + i + ": Valeur: " + valeur + ", Date: " + date + ".");
        }

    }

});
```

Im not sure about the `data: "call=test"` part by the way. I always thought that it should be something like `data: {call: "test"}`. Please refer to: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

EDIT: actually, since you're using jQuery anyways, you can also loop through the Array with .each, as suggested in the solution below.

Comment: I have this result :Entry 0: Valeur: undefined, Date: undefined.
 Entry 1: Valeur: undefined, Date: undefined.
menu=history:396 Entry 2: Valeur: undefined, Date: undefined.
menu=history:396 Entry 3: Valeur: undefined, Date: undefined.

Comment: I'll have to see your chart.php result for myself to really help you out with this one. Is it live? Can we see that page?

Comment: include_once("functions.php"); 
function test(){
 $q = intval($_GET['q']);
 $user= intval($_GET['u']);
 $histories = get_history_competences($q,$user);
 return $histories;
}

Answer (score 0):

**1) You have to encode** your response as JSON
You cant access in JS an array via string-based index!
Check it out: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**2) How to browse** the response of ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyFunction(comp_id) {
    var user_id = jQuery("#user").val();

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "chart.php?q="+comp_id+"&u="+user_id ,
    data: "call=test",
    success: function(response){

        jQuery.each(response, function(object, index) {
           alert(object.valeur + ' | ' + object.date);
        });

       // or just displayed it in your console (inspector)
       console.log(response);
     }
});
}
</script>
```

**3) PHP-Server Side**
Check this out: http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php